# Can I use any .NET Framework exception in a context of my own choosing?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am looking at the MS docs for [ParseException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.query.dynamic.parseexception?view=netframework-4.7.2). The docs say the following:

> Represents errors that occur when a LinqDataSource control parses values to create a query.

For the application I am working on I need an exception that represents a parser error. *ParseException* is a good fit but my use of the class would have absolutely nothing to do with the context Microsoft intended it to be used in.

Would it be bad form to use this class in a context of my own choosing and is it therefore better to simply write my own ParseException class?

Comment: There are some you should (`ArgumentNullException`) and some you shouldn't (`NullReferenceException`) in the `System` namespace but in most other cases, I'd say roll your own.

Comment: What about creating a class more related to your domain (maybe with a more specific name) that extends the ParseException? Doing this you will have two different types that are related to different context but have a very similar behaviour.

Comment: The fact that that type is a member of the `System.Web.Query.Dynamic` namespace means that you should not use it but rather define your own.

Comment: Agree with @Damien_The_Unbeliever. I'd also add that I generally end up using an Exception inheritance hierarchy to allow for different levels of granularity in exception handling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C#, are there any built-in exceptions I shouldn't use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763627/in-c-are-there-any-built-in-exceptions-i-shouldnt-use)

Comment: It's only beneficial to define custom exceptions if the intent is for the caller to handle them differently, or if they need to contain some contextual data.